# bash syntax error for adding '(' character in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, wildcard

I am running the following command on the Linux command line

```
cp !(non_*).txt some_folder/
```

It is working as expected (i.e., copy all *.txt files except the files starting with 'non_' in the current folder to some_folder.)

But when the same line is added to a script file and executing it with
`./script.sh`

it is throwing the following error.

```
./script.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('

./script.sh: line 1: ` cp !(oam_cfg*).txt kk/'
```

What can be the correction here?

FYI: I am trying to copy all *.txt files except the files starting with 'non_' in the current folder to some_folder.

Comment: `shopt -s extglob`

Comment: `shopt -s extglob` on its own separate line, separated by a newline before all commands afterwards, otherwise it won't work, also see: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jetchisel commented an hour ago, you need to turn on extended globbing.

An example:

```
$: touch foo.txt bar.txt  # create a file
$: echo +(foo*txt)        # use an extended glob, which fails on syntax
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
$: shopt -s extglob  # turn extended globbing *ON*
$: echo +(foo*txt)   # same command now succeeds
foo.txt
$: echo !(foo).txt   # negative works as well
bar.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But I have a doubt. How does setting the extglob flag in shell options make it work? I googled it. but couldn't get a clear understanding. Can you please brief me on what this extglob is for?.. Thanks :)

Comment: `!(non_*).txt` is not valid syntax in the usual base configuration. Setting extended globbing with `shopt -s extglob`  basically changes the parsing rules, so now that series of characters "makes sense" and becomes legal. You're telling it to use extra notation.